# Any one has uploaded application build using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6 on Play store?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is it feasible to release application build through Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6.? I have released applications on Play store through **Stable Android Studio 2.3.3** but I am not sure if I release application through **Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6** which is not stable version yet. Will it have any issue while releasing application on Play store or after that as it is not **stable version**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The APK compiling is the same (with some differences given the fact that it supports Java 8). though the IDE being unstable has nothing to do with the APK generation, it mostly affects the editor.

So you can release an APK made in a AS beta x without issues. Unlike IDE updates, it is backwards compatible. So if you decide to go back to 2.3.3 and release a new update after a beta update, that is fine.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification.